# R : multiple smoothScatter plots

Tags: r, statistics, visualization, scatter-plot

I have two sets of scatterplots. I want to use smoothScatter() but it seems that the add function does not work, I want to use separated colors for both distributions. For example:

> X1<-rnorm(1000, mean = -2, sd = 1)
>   Y1<-rnorm(1000, mean = -2, sd = 1)
>
> X2<-rnorm(1000, mean = 2, sd = 1)
>   Y2<-rnorm(1000, mean = 2, sd = 1)
>
> smoothScatter(X1,Y1,col="green",colramp=colorRampPalette(c("white",  "green")));
>   smoothScatter(X2,Y2,col="green",colramp=colorRampPalette(c("white",  "red")),add=T);

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use transparency like this  `colramp = colorRampPalette(c(rgb(1, 1, 1, 0), rgb(1, 0, 0, 1)), alpha = TRUE)` for the second function.

This will add transparency to the background of second plot.